# How to retrieve the file in JSON format in JSP?

Tags: html, json, jsp

I want to ask a question about the JSON and JSP. I have 2 JSP (JSP1 & JSP2) pages and 1 JSON format file.

Both of the JSP pages are pack into a .war file. The JSON file is stored in a web server(e.g. `http://examp;e.com`). And I have to do the following tasks:

1) Open the JSP1 (has a link)

2) When the user clicks the link, it will call the JSON file (`http://examp;e.com`)

3) Display the JSP2 and show the content of the JSON file

```
{ "class":
    {
        "number": 2,
        "student": 
        {
        "name": "Tom",
        "age": 1
        },
        "student": 
        {
        "name": "May",
        "age": 2
        }
    }
}
```

I have the basic knowledge of the HTML and the JSP, but I don't know how to do this action. Should I use the  in the JSP1, if yes, what object should I use in order to retrieve the JSON content? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

if it's only about displaying the JSON content available at some remote location into your page, you can probably use a hidden ***iframe*** linked to the location. keep the iframe invisible initially, and when the user clicks it, display it. you can use the "***display***" style property to toggle the visibility of the frame.

but remember, for this to work, the JSON text should be available as a plain text/html file. in other words, if the JSON object is present within the script tags, then you'll have to adopt a different approach.

Comment: majumdar, thank you for your reply. I still have some questions as I don't know how to use the iframe. would you mind to give me some reference for it? thank you.

Comment: you should find this [http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp] useful. the attributes which should be of interest to you are - **src**, **height**, **width**